# how to plot the graph of equation?

Tags: matlab, graph, physics

I am writing the code for the equation which is attached below ([image of equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3YtP.jpg)).
I have written the code but getting errors. I want to plot the graph of E and H as underlined in the image.

In the code I have written the code for electric field (electricField).
So can I improve the code and plot it as I want.

```
theta=0:0.05:2*pi;
f=100;
omega=2*pi*f;
Emax=11;
Bmax=11;
lambda=4000;
k=(2*pi)/lambda;

%phase_vel=omega/k*sin(theta);
%plot(theta,phase_vel);

%wavelength=lambda\sin(theta);
%plot(theta,wavelength);

beta=k;
Ei=100;
z=0:1:100;
%electricField=2j*Ei*sin(beta*z*cos(theta)).*sin(beta*x*sin(theta));
electricField=2*Ei*sin(beta.*z.*cos(theta)).*exp(-1.*beta.*x.*sin(theta));
%z=0:1:100;
%yline=animatedline('lineWidth',1,'Color','r');
zline=animatedline('lineWidth',1,'Color','b');
xline=animatedline('lineWidth',1,'Color','g');

axis([0 2*pi -11 11 0 2*pi]);
view(45,20);   

title("Electromagnetic wave");
xlabel('Propogation direction(x)');
ylabel('electric Field(Y)');
zlabel('magnetic Field(Z)');

hold on;

for i=1:length(theta)
    addpoints(xline,electricField(i),0,0);
    
    addpoints(zline,theta(i),0,electricField(i));
    drawnow
    pause(0.02);
    hold on;
end
```

ERROR:

```
Error using  * 
Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first matrix matches the number of rows in the
second matrix. To perform elementwise multiplication, use '.*'.

Error in xzfdsgs (line 22)
electricField=2*Ei*sin(beta*z*cos(theta)).*sin(beta*x*sin(theta));
```

even after replacing '*' with '.*' I am getting error:

```
Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation.

Error in xzfdsgs (line 22)
electricField=2*Ei*sin(beta.*z.*cos(theta)).*exp(-1.*beta.*x.*sin(theta));
```

Answer (score 0):

Transposing the theta (using theta') seems to work. You also haven't assigned "x" values. Check it out and see if it helps :)

Comment: ya, it working but the wave is not being plotted.